# What is the difference between different vector spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, tensor-products, tensors

What is the difference between 2 vector spaces, V and W, when a transformation(linear map) is given as

T: V->W

is it just the difference between dimensionality of the 2 spaces?

If stress tensor is viewed as a transformation(linear map), are the area vector and traction vector in different vector spaces?

Comment: @gimusi Thank you for a great answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear transformation can be defined from $T: V\to W$ without any restriction on the dimension of the two vector spaces $V$ and $W$.

The stress tensor is a map

$$T: \mathbb{R^3}\to \mathbb{R^3}, \,\vec n\to \vec t_n$$

which relates the a unit-length direction vector $\vec n$ to the stress vector $\vec t_n$ at a point across a unitary surface perpendicular to $\vec n$.

Comment: When the map is given as T:V->V the vector spaces and so the coordinate system in that space are the same. But not all maps are given as V->V. Its a special case of V->W. What could be the difference between the space V and W.

Comment: How to write stress tensor as a map between 2 vector spaces? Are the direction vector and the stress vectors in different spaces or the same space? Would there be a difference in the basis (the coordinate system) for the direction vector and the force vector or they are given by some same general coordinate system?

Comment: @GRANZER In general $V$ and $W$ can be any kind of vector space (since all vector spaces are isomorphic).

Comment: @GRANZER the stress tensor is defined as a map $T: \mathbb{R^3}\to \mathbb{R^3}$ thus in the same vector space, that is the 3 dimensional euclidean space.

Comment: When you say "any kind of vector space" can you please tell me some example of different kinds of vector spaces?

Comment: @GRANZER For example we can map matrices 3-by-3 is polynomial of degree 5.

Comment: Have you considered that the domain and codomain might be separate instances of $\mathbb R^3$ (or more likely ${\mathbb R^3}^*$ since the input is a normal to a plane)?